# Laravel middleware not attaching to some requests

Tags: laravel, request, middleware

I have a bit of an issue currently in regards to middleware.

I am using the JSON API package and I am trying to pass in some data from a header and merge it with the request.

This seems to be working perfectly fine on one route, but then on the next it seems that the request is completely empty although it's defined in the same route method.

Here is my route definition file:

```
JsonApi::register('default')->authorizer('default')->middleware('tenant.identifier')->routes(function (RouteRegistrar $api) {
    $api->resource('categories')->readOnly();
});
```

I have the middleware:

```
if (($sub = $request->header('X-Tenant-Identifier')) === null) {
            return new Response('Tenant identifier is missing from the request', Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        if (($tenant = Tenant::query()->where('subdomain', $sub)->first()) === null) {
            return new Response('Invalid tenant identifier', Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        $request->merge([
            'tenant' => $tenant,
            'requiresTenant' => true
        ]);

        return $next($request);
```

If I go to `/categories` and do a `dd(request()->all())` I can see the contents merged, however if I go to `/categories/1` I see that the `dd(request()->all())` is an empty array.

Is this the right way to approach this kind of idea, merging with the request or should I do something like the following:

```
app()->instance(Tenant::class, $tenant)
```

EDIT: doing the above and doing an instance of Tenant also doesn't work and the tenant is empty, however doing a dd($tenant) inside of the middleware I can see it has resolved...

Answer (score 0):

The middleware was dispatching find and everything was getting run - this was to do with the order that middleware is put in. Unfortunately, the package doesn't allow you to edit the order of the middleware.

In order to fix this, I made a route which had the middleware on inside of `RouteServiceProvider` and created a new file called `public.php` where I store the routes as all routes inside of this file will need the middleware anyway.

It isn't ideal but for now it's a fix.